# Best way to play sound with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to play a sound and i have found two ways that works for me.
Which is the better way and why? is a good idea add a "load" event listener?

First way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');  
  audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound.ogg');  
  audioElement.addEventListener("load", function(){  
      audioElement.play();  
  }, true);

  audioElement.play();  
});
```

Second way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  audioElement = new Audio('sound.ogg');  
  audioElement.play();  
});
```

Comment: what about network source for audio in case new Audio()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should go with the first way (with `load`), because 'DOMReady' doesn't guarantee that the sound file finish downloading, just like with Image.

Comment: but wich is the better way to initialize an audio file? `new Audio('sound.ogg');` or `document.createElement('audio');`??

Comment: AFAIK they are the same, both will create a new `HTMLAudioElement`. However the `new Audio()` constructor is the old way (as of pre-DOM1) and `document.createElement()` is the newer way (DOM2); you can not attach the element created with `new Audio()` to your document. `new Audio('sound.ogg')` is the shortcut for `var a = new Audio(); a.src = 'sound.ogg';`.

Comment: OK, I've made a test here http://jsperf.com/new-audio-vs-document-createelement-audio

Answer (score 1):

You really should use a feature detection system for this. I'd use [Modernizr to test for HTML5 audio](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5). That way you are only attempting to serve the audio to those who can get it with HTML5.

You can even [test for HTML5 features](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load) and fallback on alternative if not found by using Modernizr. These alternatives are called "polyfills" and a list of these that Modernizr supports is [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills).

The benefit of doing it this way is that you are covering all your bases in terms of browser features. I pity the fools out there still using IE7.

Comment: I know about Modernizr, but I'm trying to play sound with the <bgsound> in the IE case, and I'm using the html5shiv script instead Modernizr